# Filling DataTable From File

Tags: c#

This should be easy - I ahve a file which I need to treat as a DataTable - I ve looked at the API and it requires a IDataReader with no impl of a file based one

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/FlatFileDataReader) open source project at MS might help you.